# Search relevance across multiple table in Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, ranking

I am facing a challenge regarding `Full Text Search in SQL SERVER 2008.`

I have 2 tables A and B with their respective columns a, b .
Now, I want to do a full text search on all these 3 tables and have a combined search relevance.

That means, if the search text is found in all the two tables, it should rank higher.
If it is found only in col. a of table A, then it should rankd second
If it is found only in col. b of table B, then it should rankd third

How can this be done.

a query like this,

```
SELECT A.a, B.b, C.c, a.Title, akt.[Rank] + bkt.[Rank] /2  AS [Rank]
    FROM PublicationSearch b
    INNER JOIN Publication a ON a.Id = b.Id
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(B, b, 'search text') bkt ON b.Id = bkt.[Key] 

ORDER BY [Rank] DESC
```

Whats is happening is, it is showing me search results if the search result exist in both the tables with proper rank.

But, if the search result is only in one table, then its not showing.
If I apply a `LEFT JOIN`, then the records are coming, but with `RANK = Null`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT A.a, B.b, akt.[Rank] + bkt.[Rank] /2  AS [Rank]
    FROM B b
    INNER JOIN Publication a ON a.Id = b.Id
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(B, b, 'search text') bkt ON b.Id = bkt.[Key]

ORDER BY [Rank] DESC

UNION

SELECT A.a, null as B.b, akt.[Rank] as [Rank]
    FROM A a
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]

UNION

SELECT null as A.a, B.b, bkt.[Rank] as [Rank]
    FROM B b
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(A, a, 'search text') akt ON a.Id = akt.[Key]

The above query is for searching records ( using rankings) across two tables.
The first query : Only those records will be displayed where the search text is in both the columns  of the two tables.

Second query : Only those records where searchtext is only in column a of table A

Third query :  Only those records where searchtext is only in column b of table B

My question is, if I have to search across 4 or 5 tables, the number of UNIONS will increase like crazy. It will be too complicated and slow as well.

So , is there any other method which could reduce these UNIONS
I tried Views, but they cannot be full text indexed.

Any ideas..
Thanks,
Marcus